# How to make discord bot calc with javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I'm new to this ,i am looking for simple mathematics command on discord.js im building a simple bot for myself .I want him to calc simple task like : Some Call !Calc 35.5 768.99 666566.3
and the bot calc the first Num1 with preset number like !Calc 10.5 21 30.5 and it will answer back
10.5x3 ---> 31.5 , 21x10 ---> 210 , 30.5/3 ---> 10.16666666
preset number are *3 *10 and /3 ... I'm already running a bot with the basic setup that he answer back at !ping etc...
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score -2):

You can try using mathjs, you can download it with nodejs.
By `npm install maths` in your terminal.

[You may check out documentation here.](https://mathjs.org/docs/)

Here is the template I have made in reference of mathjs.

```js
const math = require('mathjs');

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    let Equation = message.content.substring(message.content.indexOf(" ")).slice(1);
    let resp = math.evaluate(Equation);

})
```

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @Quentin Thank You! I have added a template of using it for the package I have inserted

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,i did add it to my bot.js and trying to understand how i could trigger it :)